# vim codewalk through

Tags: vim

Following code has been picked up from [this blog](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/1986730994/keep-your-privates-close)

```
function! Privatize()
  let priorMethod = PriorMethodDefinition()
  exec "normal iprivate :" . priorMethod  . "\<Esc>=="
endfunction

function! PriorMethodDefinition()
  let lineNumber = search('def', 'bn')
  let line       = getline(lineNumber)
  if line == 0
    echo "No prior method definition found"
  endif
  return matchlist(line, 'def \(\w\+\).*')[1]
endfunction

map <Leader>p :call Privatize()<CR>
```

I tried but I fail to understand PriorMethodDefinition method. Can someone walk me through this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PriorMethodDefinition` returns the name of the first method definition above the cursor.

It does this by `search`ing backwards for a line containing the text 'def'. The search function returns the line number and `getline` is used to retrieve the content of that line.

The function checks that it has found a valid line, before using a regular expression to get the name of the method and return it.

You can read more about these functions if you're curious about the specifics - see:

```
:help search
:help getline
:help matchlist
```

**Edit**: you can also read about the regular expression pattern

```
:help pattern
```

But I found it a little confusing at first, so allow me to explain it a little. Here's the expression used:

```
'def \(\w\+\).*'
```

This will search for any text matching the following pattern: "the text `def` followed by one or more 'word' characters `\w\+` followed by zero or more characters `.*`". The part matching the word characters is placed into a group (or atom), designated by the escaped parens `\(` & `\)`. More info on the definitions of word characters etc can be found in the help link above.

The `matchlist` function returns a list of matches, the first `[0]` of which is the full text matching the regex, followed by submatches (ie our group). We are interested in the first such submatch, hence the `[1]`.

Comment: awesome. Your answer has given me some pointers to start reading the vim book. thanks.

Comment: The built in help is great, but you need to learn what to look for and how it works. I'll often start looking in the help pages, resort to a google search if that doesn't work, and then go back to the help pages for more detailed info once I know what I'm looking for.